# LogParser: Find all log rows where session cookie = the session cookie found in a row that had an error

Tags: iis-7, logparser

Looking for examples of integrating LP into  this workflow:

1. A SQL server event indicates IIS
   tossed an error.
2. SQL parses the body of the error
   message and generates an LP
   commandline that queries IIS logs to
   collect more information.
3. An email is dispatched to tech
   support with a link to an html (or
   .aspx) page that would run and
   present LP's output.

So i think the question boils down to:

How do i hook LP upto IIS7?

EDIT: Ok...re-boiling the question. When an IIS exception is triggered I want to see all the other log rows where the session cookie is the same as the session cookie found in the error event. Yes, I could live with polling IIS logs via a scheduled task - that takes ELMAH/SQL out of the equation.

But now the question becomes:
    **Find all log rows where session cookie = the session cookie found in a row that had an error**

Comment: I am unclear how #1 happens -- how does SQL Server know that IIS has an error?

Comment: ELMAH (my asp.net app's error handler) inserts a record to sql. The OnInsert trigger will give me the opportunity to parse the event body, extract/parse the fields i need, generate LP's command, and email the sysadmin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could setup a reoccurring Windows job that interrogates the IIS logs with LP every 10 minutes or so and use the checkpoint so it only looks at the unchecked parts of the logs. It's not integrating with IIS, but might solve the problem.